# Animate a view to slide in and slide out of the screen in android

Tags: android

Good day i have a view that is programmatically placed at the bottom left part of a SurfaceView and what i want is when a button is clicked, the view slides out of the screen and slides back in but nothing seems to happen in the animation. Here is my code, i will just put the relevant parts:

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_Info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#6444"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/medium_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="med"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dimensions_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="dimen" />


</LinearLayout>
```

positioning the view:

```
RelativeLayout.param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 240);
                            param.leftMargin = 0;

                            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_info, null);
                            mylayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.gallery_Info_root_id);  //what i want to animate

                            view.setLayoutParams(param);

                             param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                             param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

                             view.getLayoutParams().width = 380;

                            RelativeLayout lContainerLayout = new RelativeLayout(VideoPlayback.this);
                            lContainerLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));

                            lContainerLayout.addView(view);
                            addContentView(lContainerLayout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

slide in and slide out animation:

```
    private void slideInView(){

    Animation slidein = new MyTranslateAnimation(mylayout, -mylayout.getWidth(), 0, 0, 0);
    slidein.setDuration(animationDuration);
    slidein.setInterpolator(interpolator);      
    mylayout.startAnimation(slidein);

}

private void slideOutView(){

    Animation slidein = new MyTranslateAnimation(mylayout, 0, -mylayout.getWidth(), 0, 0);
    slidein.setDuration(animationDuration);
    slidein.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    mylayout.startAnimation(slidein);

}
```

MyTranslateAnimation which i got from [here](https://github.com/weakwire/3PaneLayout/tree/master/src/com/example)

```
public class MyTranslateAnimation extends Animation {

  private View view;
  private final float fromX;
  private final float toX;
  private final float fromY;
  private final float toY;


    public MyTranslateAnimation(View v, float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY) {
        view = v;
        this.fromX = fromX;
        this.toX = toX;
        this.fromY = fromY;
        this.toY = toY;
        setDuration(500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        float x = (toX-fromX) * interpolatedTime + fromX;
        float y = (toY - fromY) * interpolatedTime + fromY;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins((int)x, (int)y, 0, 0);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Please can anyone spot anything i am doing wrong? because i can't seem to see why i can't slide "mylayout" in and out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but why are you using a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams instead of LinearLayout? I don't see a RelativeLayout on your layout.xml .

Comment: well i wanted to take advantage of the positioning that RelativeLayout  offers since i was positioning it on a surfaceView.

Comment: Ok, but you have to change your LinearLayout in RelativeLayout.